# Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component - error on setup with Context

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm getting the 'Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. ' error when I log into my app and redirect to homepage.

I'm using Context to see if the user is logged in and check every couple of minutes if the token is still valid.

So far I narrowed the error down to the logIn() method in AuthProvider but I'm not sure how to fix it - this Component is mounted at all times, so the problem must be with LoginForm Component being unmounted.

Here is the minimal example that reproduces the error:

**App.tsx**

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <AuthProvider>
        <HashRouter>
          <Routes />
        </HashRouter>
      </AuthProvider>
    </div>
  );
};

const Routes = () => {
  const Auth = React.useContext(AuthContext);
  return (
    <Switch>
      <ProtectedRoute path={"/home"} auth={Auth.isAuthenticated} component={HomePage} />
      <ProtectedLogin path={"/"} auth={Auth.isAuthenticated} component={LoginPage} />
      <Redirect to="/" />
    </Switch>
  );
};

const ProtectedRoute = ({ auth, component: Component, ...rest }: any) => {
  return <Route {...rest} render={() => auth ? (<Component />) : (<Redirect to="/"/>)} />;
};

const ProtectedLogin = ({ auth, component: Component, ...rest }: any) => {
  return <Route {...rest} render={() => !auth ? (<Component />) : (<Redirect to="/home"/>)} />;
};


export default App;
```

**login-page.component.tsx**

```
export default class LoginPage extends Component<IProps, IState> {

  render(): ReactElement {
    return (
      <div className="container card-wrapper">
        <div className="card mt-5 login">
          <div className="card-body p-5">
            <LoginForm />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**login-form.component.tsx**

```
const LoginForm = () => {
  const [redirect, setRedirect] = useState(false);
  const Auth = React.useContext(AuthContext);

  if (redirect) {
    return <Redirect to="/home" />;
  }

  return (
    <Formik
      initialValues={{ email: "", password: "" }}
      onSubmit={(formValues: FormikValues) => {
        ApiService.post("user/authenticate", formValues)
          .then((res: any) => {
            Auth.logIn({token: res.token});
            Auth.initTokenChecking();
            setRedirect(true);
          })
          .catch(() => console.log('error'));
      }}
      validationSchema={Yup.object().shape({
        email: Yup.string(),
        password: Yup.string()
      })}
    >
      {(props) => {
        const {
          values,
          isSubmitting,
          handleChange,
          handleSubmit,
        } = props;
        return (
          <div>
            <form className="form-group mb-3" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <div className="mb-4">
                <VWTextInputField
                  required={true}
                  label="E-mail"
                  name="email"
                  value={values.email}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="mb-4">
                <VWPasswordField
                  required={true}
                  label="Password"
                  name="password"
                  value={values.password}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="d-grid">
                <button
                  type="submit"
                  className="btn btn-block btn-primary"
                  disabled={isSubmitting}
                >
                  Log in
                </button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        );
      }}
    </Formik>
  );
};

export default LoginForm;
```

**auth.jsx**

```
const AuthContext = React.createContext();
export class AuthProvider extends Component {
  _interval = null;
  state = {
    isAuthenticated: false,
    user: null,
  };

  logIn = (user) => {
    this.setState({ user, isAuthenticated: true });
    localStorage.setItem("token", JSON.stringify(user.token));
  };

  logOut = () => {
    if (this._interval) {
      clearInterval(this._interval);
    }
    this.setState({ user: null, isAuthenticated: false });
    localStorage.clear();
  };

  initTokenChecking = () => {
    this._interval = setInterval(() => {
      if (!localStorage.getItem("token")) {
        this.logOut();
      }
      const token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("token"));
      console.log(jwt_decode(token));
      if (jwt_decode(token).exp < Date.now() / 1000) {
        this.logOut();
      }
    }, 2 * 60 * 1000);
  };

  render() {
    const { user, isAuthenticated } = this.state;
    const { logIn, logOut, initTokenChecking } = this;
    return (
      <AuthContext.Provider
        value={{
          user,
          isAuthenticated,
          logIn,
          logOut,
          initTokenChecking,
        }}
      >
        {this.props.children}
      </AuthContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}
export default AuthContext;
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing redundant `setRedirect(true);` in `login-component.tsx` fixed the error